# Nginx location exact match matches beyond arguement

Tags: nginx

In my nginx config, I would like to catch `/foo-bar/` and do a rewrite using location, but for it to ignore `/foo-bar/anything-else`.

I've tried:

```
location = /foo-bar/ {
```

and

```
location ~ ^/foo-bar/$ {
```

and

```
location ~ /foo-bar/ {
```

but it also catches and rewrites

```
/foo-bar/?t=aaa-bbb-ccc
```

How do I catch only

```
/foo-bar/
```

and not

```
/foo-bar/?t=aaa-bbb-ccc
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: by /foo/anything-else do you then actually mean /foo/?anything-else

Comment: The right operator should be `=`. Did you try `location = /foo {` as maybe `/foo/` didn't match...

Comment: Martin - yes, you are correct. The URI is really `/foo-bar/?t=aaa-bbb-cc`. How does the '?' affect the location match? Iv

Comment: I've updated my original question to reflect the '?'.

Comment: ring0 - yes, I tried `location = /foo {` but the link i want to redirect has a '/' at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment thread in cnst answer, I used:

```
if ($request_uri = "/foo-bar/") { rewrite ^ … permanent; }
```

and I never used

```
/location/
```

Comment: You should probably `last` the rewrite. http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Answer (score 1):

```
location = /foo/ {
    rewrite  ^  …  redirect;
}
location ~ /foo/ {
    return  404;
}
```

If this doesn't work, it must be the infamous permanent caching of the `301 Moved Permanently` responses — try your request with `curl -v` to make sure it works or doesn't work, and/or clear the whole cache of your Gecko or other browser (in Gecko there is no other way around it (other than clearing the whole cache) — the Shift-refresh trick does not apply to `301`).

---

Update: if you also need to ensure that no args are accepted (e.g. /foo/?test), then use the following:

```
location = /foo/ {
    if ($args) { return 403; }
    rewrite  ^  …  redirect;
}
```

Comment: Hi cnst. I tried the above config with `curl -v` and I am still being redirected.

Comment: No way, absolutely impossible.  It'll only redirect from "/foo/", anything below "/foo/" will return a Not Found message; if that's not the case, then you must have something else you're not telling us about, or, perhaps, you are forgetting to restart nginx with the correct configuration.

Comment: Did you restart `nginx` after that?

Comment: Ya, I've been restarting nginx all along.

Comment: Hi @cnst, 

Sorry that last comment was accidentally posted (I've deleted it). The ? is tripping it up (as MartinFjordvald suggested above). The 404 returns as you suggested.
Here are some test pages I've setup:
http://tourdafrique.com/foo-bar/ _redirects to_ http://tourdafrique.com/redirected-to-test-page/ **and**
http://tourdafrique.com/foo-bar/test _returns 404_ **and**
http://tourdafrique.com/foo-bar/?test _redirects to_ http://tourdafrique.com/redirected-to-test-page/

Comment: Well, you didn't tell us that!  That's a completely different question now!

Comment: Anyhow, I've updated my answer, based on your new question.  If it doesn't return 404 for `/foo/?`, and you still want it to (I don't understand what would be the usecase), then that one is also possible to catch, but you'd have to use `$request_uri`, and I don't really recommend going there.

Comment: what I'm aiming for is if there are any $args, then process the URL like normal, but if there aren't any $args, then do the redirect. It catches the URL without args using `if ($args = '')` but will deliver a 404 if there are not args. I've tried several statements after the if statement in the location block, but I can't get it to "continue on as normal".

Comment: a third totally different question?  you have to be kidding us! place the following within your "like normal" location: `if ($request_uri = "/foo-bar/") { rewrite  ^  …  redirect;}`

Comment: cnst - `if ($request_uri = "/foo-bar/") { rewrite ^ … redirect;}` is the fix (though I used permanent instead `if ($request_uri = "/foo-bar/") { rewrite ^ … permanent;}`). My apologies for leading you down the 'location' path... I'm not experienced with nginx and I'm working with a config I didn't initially setup.