# Nginx allow access if custom header is present

Tags: nginx, web-server

Is there a way I could allow access to a directory only if certain custom header is present and the value matches? With apache, I've been doing it with SetEnvIf. How could I do it with nginx?

Basically I have a dev server that should be accessed only by me, but I have dynamic ip and have to change config file everyday. With apache, I just set my browser to send a custom header that acted like an access password and apache would allow access if that header value was correct.

Answer (score 8):

I researched a lot to solve a simple problem: Only allow proxy_pass if request have a specific token in the header. I tried all the answers here and nothing worked how I liked. My final solution is:

```
location /api {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    if ($http_authorization != "Bearer 1234") {
        return 401;
    }

    proxy_pass http://app:3000/;
}
```

**References:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734332/nginx-not-equal-to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431496/nginx-read-custom-header-from-upstream-server

[Nginx location exact match matches beyond arguement](https://serverfault.com/questions/490760/nginx-location-exact-match-matches-beyond-arguement)

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: if you want to use the `Authorization` header, you can use then `auth_basic` that uses it as built in directive without reinventing the wheel.

See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

Comment: For my case, the infrastructure team allowed only tokens to make the authentication.

Comment: Well then, it was not easy. I know well that some setups are very limiting.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual question is answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong

Having said that, why not use Basic Auth? That makes it a password, instead of acting like one.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html